# Grab Social Links from URL

Tags: javascript, url, web-scraping, social-networking

Im looking to see if i can enter a URL into a form and then using that URL grab the social links from that URL, Facebook, twitter and instagram in this instance, ideally looking to achieve this using javascript. This illustrates a small part in a larger project.

Comment: What do you mean by "social links" ? Do you mean find the share buttons on that page? That would probably heavily depend on which website(s) you're scraping. I'd start with a few example pages, see what their html formatting has in common. I expect it would be very difficult to get something that grabs those buttons universally.

Comment: @OmarShehata what i mean is from the web URL grab the links to the brands social pages example www.example.com then grab any social links from that URL like www.facebook.com/example and www.twitter.com/example. No buttons or share values, just the brands social presence